# Graphics not centered

Tags: c, visual-studio, opengl, glut

I have been working on a graphics project in C using Codeblocks and Glut lib.
Everything was going well and then tried it in Visual Studio Express 2013 RC.
In VSE my graphics are no longer centered in the window. 
Look to be shifted about 2% to the left and top.
I have defined everything I can think of

```
glutInitWindowSize(1000, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); // Set the position of the window
```

Reshape function looks like this

```
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);   // multiply by new coordinates.
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

initialization is this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);            // Select the matrix to change,
glLoadIdentity();                       // clear it,
gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);   // multiply by new coordinates.
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
glLineWidth(1.0);
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: do you want window to be centered on your screen? or the graphics inside the viewport?

Comment: I mean the graphics inside the viewport. When i draw a line from -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0 it is not intersecting the corners the way one would expect and is slightly offset. I don't get this in Code Blocks. I can adjust it with gluOrtho2D or glTranslate but just wondering why. It seems to include the viewport boarders as part of the window size.

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with your code if you are going to use line smoothing. First your blend function is wrong, it should be: `glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE);` when you go to draw a line. Second, you need a destination alpha channel for this to work (that means in GLUT, you need `GL_RGBA` and not `GL_RGB`). I do not know what pixel format you are using, but it needs to be `GL_RGBA` for line smoothing to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you mean glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); ? When I use your suggested constants I get a blank screen